# What's the reasoning for not allowing default constructor in inner class when used by outer class?

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, language-lawyer

The following fails to compile with clang (in c++14):

```
struct A {
    struct B
    {
        int c = 0;
    };

    void a(B b = B()) {}
};
```

Implementing the constructor for B manually and setting c in the initialization list works as expected:

```
struct A {
    struct B
    {
        int c;
        B(): c(0) {}
    };

    void a(B b = B()) {}
};
```

What's the reasoning for not allowing the former construct? A side note is that msvc compiles both examples.

Edit: The given error is:

```
source_file.cpp:8:13: error: cannot use defaulted default constructor of 'B' within 'A' outside of member functions because 'c' has an initializer
        int c = 0;
            ^
source_file.cpp:11:18: note: implicit default constructor for 'A::B' first required here
    void a(B b = B()) {}
```

Comment: "*The following fails to compile with clang*" Which version of Clang? And what error does it give?

Comment: 3.8.0, you can test the code here: https://rextester.com/ZDI57994

Comment: Isn't 3.8 a bit... old?

Comment: Confirmed with gcc-8.2 as well, and clang-7.0.0. https://godbolt.org/z/EluYOF

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36684 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88165

Comment: There is no reasoning, it is a bug.  Closed as a dupe.

Comment: @NathanOliver wondering why on both compilers, though. Did someone peek at other one's codes?

Comment: @SergeyA It's happened a few times that I've seen.  Normally it's more a library bug but I've also seen compiler bugs where both clang and gcc get it wrong but msvs and/or icc will have it right.

Comment: @NathanOliver makes sense - the other two are not open source :)

Comment: Note that C++ does not have a formal notion of "inner class" or "outer class". Other languages use those terms with a rather specific meaning that does not apply in C++. In general, `B` would be referred to as a "nested class" and `A` would be the "containing class".